# Sum of derivative of integrals: $f(x)=\left(\int\limits_0 ^{x} e^{-t^2}dt\right)^2$ and $g(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

> For all $x$ in $\mathbb R$ define $\displaystyle f(x)=\left(\int_0 ^{x} e^{-t^2}dt\right)^2$ and $\displaystyle g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt$. Show that for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$
>   $f'(x)+g'(x)=0$

I did:

$\displaystyle f'(x)=2\left( \int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt\right)e^{-x^2}$ and
$\displaystyle g'(x)=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}(-2x)dt$ then changing $xt\rightarrow t$

$\displaystyle g'(x)=-2x e^{-x^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt$ , finally

$\displaystyle f'(x)+g'(x)=2(1-x)e^{-x^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt$ then this is equal to zero only if x=1.

Am i missing something? thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a minor error, almost but not quite a typo.  When you substituted, "changing" $xt$ to $t$, there were two slips.

I think the slips could have been avoided if you had made the substitution in slightly different language, letting $u=xt$.  Then $du=(x)dt$, which absorbs the extra $x$ in the integral.  And your $e^{t^2}$ should be, in my notation, $e^{-u^2}$ (this really was a typo).

With these minor corrections, things work out fine.

There must be a more conceptual way of doing it, though the computational approach you took is reasonable, and works quickly enough.

Comment: Oh yes you are so right and i must pay more atention to changing variables.

Comment: @missing314: Yes, in $xt$ "becoming" $t$, halfway in between what is $t$?  It just invites error!  Using a different letter is good insurance against such error.