# Solving exercise with Leibniz rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm asked to prove that if $f(x) = \left(\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt \right)^2$ and $g(x) = \displaystyle\int_0^1 \displaystyle\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt$ then $f'(x)+g'(x)=0$ and conclude that $f(x)+g(x)=\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I'm having some problems proving the first equality, but here's what I tried: For $f$ I just applied the chain rule: $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\left(\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt \right)^2 = 2\left(\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt \right)\left(\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt\right) = 2\left(\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt \right)\left(e^{-x^2}\right) = 2e^{-x^2}\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$.

And for $g$ I used Leibniz's Rule  $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\displaystyle\int_0^1 \displaystyle\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt = \displaystyle\int_0^1 \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\displaystyle\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}\right)dt $
$= \displaystyle\int_0^1 \displaystyle\frac{-2x(t^2+1)e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt = -2x\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}dt$.

Now, how can I prove that $f'+g'=0$?. I can't add the former integrals, to do so I should have both integrals from 0 to 1, which I tried to do as follows:

Considering the first integral, taking the change of variables $u=\displaystyle\frac{t}{x}$ I'll have $\displaystyle\frac{du}{dx} =-\displaystyle\frac{t}{x^2}=-\displaystyle\frac{u}{x}$ and then for the first integral I'd have considering the change of variables $2e^{-x^2}\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt= 2e^{-x^2}\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{-u^2x^2}\left(-\displaystyle\frac{u}{x}\right)du$.

But the latter one it seems to me that it isn't closer at all to an integral that I could add to the second one and have zero as a result.

Did I mess up with the derivatives?, or the way I'm trying to solve the problem isn't the way at all?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems your derivatives are correct and I would also try doing it this way... I'll look at it some more :)

Comment: Looks like that the second integral can be computed. Have you tried that? I will confess that I didn't look at it very closely.

Comment: Second integral: put $e^{-x^2}$ in front and then substitution $u=tx$

Comment: Yup, that does it. I checked.

Comment: See also [Sum of derivative of integrals: $f(x)=\left(\int\limits_0 ^{x} e^{-t^2}dt\right)^2$ and $g(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42365) and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/42365).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second integral $I=-2x\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}dt=-2xe^{-x^2}\int_0^1 e^{-x^2t^2}dt=-2xe^{-x^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-s^2}\frac{1}{x}ds$ where $s=tx$. Finally, $\displaystyle I=-2e^{-x^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt$