# Prove that $F(x)^2+G(x)=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: integration

> Let $F,G$ be defined by: $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt$$$$G(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}\mathrm dt$$
>   Prove that $F(x)^2+G(x)=\frac{\pi}{4}$

I can prove that $F(x),G(x)$ are derivable. And:
$$F'(x)=e^{-x^2}$$$$G'(x)=\int_{0}^{1}-2x(t^2+1)e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}\mathrm dt=\int_{0}^{-2x^2}e^u\mathrm du=e^{-2x^2}-1$$, with $u=-x^2(t^2+1)$

And then I try to prove that $2F'(x)F(x)+G'(x)=0$

But I can't finish my proof.

Comment: No I can't, the aim of this problem  to prove that $F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ when $x\to\infty$

Comment: See also [Sum of derivative of integrals: $f(x)=\left(\int\limits_0 ^{x} e^{-t^2}dt\right)^2$ and $g(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42365) and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/42365).

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$2F'(x)F (x)+G'(x)=0 \implies $$
$$F^2 (x)+G (x)=constant=$$
$$=F^2 (0)+G (0) $$

$$=G (0)=\int_0^1\frac {dt}{1+t^2} $$
$$=\arctan (1)=\frac {\pi}{4} $$

Comment: Thank you but can you give some hints to prove that $F(x)^2+G(x)=constant$?

Comment: Why this sanction. what is wrong.

Comment: I didn't put -1 for your answer, I just don't know how to prove $F(x)^2+G(x)=cst$

Comment: I upvoted, it looks fine to me, I was about to write a similar answer.  It is easy to prove that F(x)^2+G(x)=c from the first line, because the first line is the derivative of that, which is zero.  To prove the first line, just sub in the formulas from the question and compute.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here: your differentiation of $G$ is wrong, and the change of variables doesn't work like that (you have to differentiate with respect to $t$ when changing variables, not $x$, which is constant inside the integral).

You should have
$$ G'(x) = \int_0^1 -2xe^{-x^2(1+t^2)} dt, $$
and setting $t=xu$, $dt=x\,du$, so
$$ F(x) = \int_0^1 xe^{-x^2u^2} du. $$
Then, since $F'(x)=e^{-x^2}$, we have
$$ 2F'(x)F(x) = 2e^{-x^2}\int_0^1 xe^{-x^2u^2} du = \int_0^1 2xe^{-x^2(1+t^2)} dt = -G'(x) $$
changing the label on the integration variable in $F$.

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand why G'(x) is diffenrentiate wrt t. I think that this link shows that it should be x https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Parameter-dependent_integral

Comment: Oh, I see, there's somthing wrong in my calculate. Thanks again