# value of $f'(\sqrt π)+g'(\sqrt π)?$

Tags: integration

Let 
$$f(x)=\left(\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}dt\right)^2$$
and

$$g(x)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-x^2(1+t^2)}} {1+t^2} dt$$

Then what is the value of$$f'(\sqrt π)+g'(\sqrt π)?$$ I don't know how to solve this. But I guess in $g(x)$ we need to use gamma function.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @DonAntonio Why is $g$ a constant?

Comment: @Botond Mistake: didn't see that little $\;x\;$ in the exponent of $\;e\;$ ...

Comment: But in f(x), whole square is given,so how to  use Leibniz rule?

Comment: I think $(f^2)'=2f*f'$ should be used.

Comment: See also: [Sum of derivative of integrals: $f(x)=\left(\int\limits_0 ^{x} e^{-t^2}dt\right)^2$ and $g(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42365) and [Math competition integral problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3425810).

Answer (score 3):

One has

$$f’(x)=2e^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt $$

And

$$\begin{align}g’(x)&=-\int_0^12{(1+t^2)xe^{-x^2(1+t^2)}\over 1+t^2}dt \\&=-2x\int_0^1e^{-x^2(1+t^2)}dt\end{align}$$

This leads to

$$\begin{align}f’(\sqrt{\pi})+g’(\sqrt{\pi})&=2e^{-\pi}\left(\int_0^{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-t^2}dt-\sqrt{\pi}\int_0^1e^{-\pi t^2}dt\right)\\&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: For g'(x), have u used DUIS?

Comment: Yes and it is quite obvious in this case because the integral is defined and the intégrante is smooth

Comment: Ok.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$f'(x)=2\left(\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}dt\right)\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}dt\right)=2\left(\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}dt\right)\cdot e^{-x^2}$$
and

$$g'(x)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[e^{-x^2(1+t^2)}\right]} {1+t^2} dt$$